What is the grounds for barring a 3rd party culprit defence in a criminal trial?
I read in the news that the judge in the Karen Read murder trial barred her attorneys from arguing that the victim had been killed by a third party (not the defendant). What would be the legal grounds, if any, for a judge barring an attorney for making such an argument.

Do you have a link to an account of this ruling? The availability of current or recent trial court rulings can be patchy. Presumably, the case you mean is this nine week trial https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/karen-read-trial-murder-verdict-john-okeefe-rcna158895 which ended in a mistrial today because the jury could not reach a verdict.

It appears that this defense was not barred and that the premise of the question is flawed: "Read's lawyers were allowed to present a third-party culprit defense — a theory of O'Keefe's death that differed from the prosecution's — and they pointed to an agent with the Bureau of Alcohol, Tobacco, Firearms and Explosives who'd traded flirtatious texts with Read as a possible suspect in O'Keefe's death." (from the same link).

@ohwilleke "she said she was “well within my rights” to exclude the third-party defense based on arguments presented last Friday at the final pretrial hearing. “I’m going to give you a chance to develop it through relevant, competent, admissible evidence,” Cannone said but added it cannot be included in opening statements, where prosecution and defense argue their version of events." from multiple news outlets. The judge barred the defense from mentioning a third party culprit in opening statements.

Very hard to tell what the issues were without more information. There is a rule that you can't include facts in an opening statement that you can show a good faith ability to deliver upon with admissible evidence at trial and that could be what was going on, but it is hard to know without hearing/reading the arguments made by the parties legally on that issue. Any answer would be a guess at best without more information.
